# How would rsync behave if the files it is backing up are updated during the process?

Tags: file, concurrency, synchronization, rsync, race-condition

Currently doing some R&D about file synchronization, I eventually stumbled upon rsync (who wouldn't ?).

Context: There's a server used as central file repository, that is updated only by an admin. Several users synchronize their filesystem from the central repo. It's one-way sync, meaning that users will never update the repository. The updates are made with **rsync**.

Let's consider a little scenario:

1. User starts updating files from the server and downloads file A
2. Admin updates the files A and B on the server, creating A' and B'

Question: **What will be the third step ?**

- User downloads B'. He has A and B', resulting in an inconsistent state among files
- User downloads B. He has A and B, resulting in a consistent but outdated state
- User downloads B' and A', resulting in a consistent and up-to-date state
- Anything else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it's your first option: User will have A and B'. The only way to avoid this is to snapshot your filesystem before the rsync, but somehow this feels like massive overkill.

Other solutions might be

- put A and B together in one zip/tar file (the administrator/the one updating, has to do this; else files can still be updated between adding the first and second file
- Use git (or another VCS) as central repository

Comment: Thanks, this helps :) VCS could be a good solution, I'll have a deeper look at it.